# Ajax on sucess set the value of field to empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I want to empty the listed field value to empty on success. In the following code a url is called and passed value to the page and on that page the values are get and inserted in to mysql, so on succees function I want the field from which the value is get to become empty.

```
$('#datacouform').click(function() {
    var couname = $('#namecoun').attr('value');
    var coucode = $('#codecoun').attr('value');
    if ((couname === '') || (coucode === '')) {
        $('p#errorcou').show(200);
        return false;
    }
    else if ((!couname.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) || (!coucode.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/))) {
        $('p#errorcou').hide(20);
        $('p#errorcou').show(50);
        return false;
    } else {
        $('a#counloader').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'adddata.php',
            data: 'counname=' + couname + '&councode=' + coucode,
            success: function() {
                $('a#counloader').hide();
                $('#addcountryform').hide(400);
                $('#addcountry').show(400);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that '#namecoun' and '#codecoun' are just inputs, I made a few tweaks to the code snippet you gave. Try the following:

```
$('#datacouform').click(function() {
    var couname = $('#namecoun').val();
    var coucode = $('#codecoun').val();
    if ((couname.length == 0) || (coucode.length == 0)) {
        $('p#errorcou').show(200);
    } else if ((!couname.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) || (!coucode.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/))) {
        $('p#errorcou').hide(20);
        $('p#errorcou').show(50);
    } else {
        $('a#counloader').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'adddata.php',
            data: 'counname=' + couname + '&councode=' + coucode,
            success: function() {
                //RESET VALUES TO EMPTY
                $('#namecoun').val('');
                $('#codecoun').val('');
                $('a#counloader').hide();
                $('#addcountryform').hide(400);
                $('#addcountry').show(400);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Instead of using ".attr('value')" to grab the value of the input, I used jQuery .val() which returns the value as a string. I then used ".length" to see whether the values were empty or not. I removed the returns as it's implied. Using the same .val() function, you can assign values to those inputs by placing a string in the parameters like .val('value'). In this case, we want the fields empty so I gave it an empty string .val('')

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

To echo what others have already said, to get the value of an element - you should really be using the val() function.

```
$('#namecoun').val();  //get the value of the element
```

Then if you supply .val() an argument, it will set the value of the element (rather than getting it).

```
$('#namecoun').val(''); // set (empty) the value of the element
```

There is also nicer ways to do POST in jQuery; i.e

```
$.post({
    url: "adddata.php",
    data: { counname : counname,
            councode : coucode },
    success: function(){
        $('#namecoun').val('');
        /* and so on... */
    }
});
```

It's just a shortcut to what you have done, however, passing the data in such a way saves string operations. Alternatively, use the serialize function.

Also, don't return false. It's bad practice and does multiple things, as well as can be confusing when you're maintaining someone else's code and all you see are "return false"; even when the correct event occurs. What you are looking for is preventdefault. Like this..

```
$('#example').click( function(e){
    /* code here */
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Theres more information on the reasons not to return false [here](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/).

Answer (score 0):

You can clear text input value with this:

```
$('#inputId').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better to get values

```
var couname = $('#namecoun').val();
var coucode = $('#codecoun').val();
```

To empty these inputs put these lines inside your `success` callback function.

```
$('#namecoun').val('');
$('#codecoun').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
var couname = $('#namecoun').val();
```

to get consistent results when getting the value of an input element. Then if you want to set the value, just use

```
$('#namecoun').val('')
```